# How do I load a node module as if the current module were located somewhere else?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, require

I have some nodejs code running in a module somewhere. From this module, I would like to load a module located in a completely different place in the file system -- for example, given the path `"/another/dir"` and the module name `"foo"`, I would like Node to act as if a module running in `/another/dir` had called `require("foo")`, rather than my own module.

```
  My code is running here
/some/folder/node_modules/mine/my_module.js

  I have the path "/another/dir/", the string "foo",
    and want to load this module
/another/dir/node_modules/foo/index.js
```

In other words, the [module documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_all_together) refers to the process *"require(X) from module at path Y"*, and I would like to specify my own value for `Y`

Can this be accomplished? If so, how? If not, why not?

Comment: Correct me if I'm getting this wrong. You want to load an installed module from a package `/another/dir/` in your `/some/folder/` package, but that `foo` module would work if some of its dependencies are not installed in `/some/folder`? Also people proposed to add the `node_modules` path to `modules.path` but if both packages have some of the same dependencies installed wouldn't this be a problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The simplest, is just to resolve the path into an absolute path, this will be the recommended approach for most if not all cases.

```
var path = require('path');

var basedir = '/another/dir';
var filename = 'foo'; // renamed from dirname

var filepath = path.join(basedir, 'node_modules', filename);
var imports = require(filepath);
```

If you **really need** to make require act as if it is in a different directory,
you can push the base directory to `module.paths`

```
module.paths.unshift('/another/dir/node_modules');

var imports = require('foo');

module.paths.shift();
```

`module.paths` can also be modified externally via the environment variable `NODE_PATH`, tho that would be the least recommended approach *but* this does apply it globally across all modules.

Answer (score 7):

### A symlink with npm link

To avoid problems or modify source code I would use [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link), from your example:

First:

```
cd /another/dir/node_modules/foo  # go into the package directory
npm link                          # creates global link
```

This will create a global link for the `foo` module, on Linux you need root permissions to do this.

Then:

```
cd /some/folder/ # go into some other package directory.
npm link foo     # link-install the package
```

`/some/folder/package.json` should contain `foo` as a dep, is not mandatory, without it you get an `extraneous` warning with `npm ls`:

```
"dependencies": {
    [...]
    "foo": "*"
  }
```

### No symlink with local NODE_PATH

You don't like symlinks ? You can still use `NODE_PATH` but locally instead setting a global variable as @rocketspacer suggested, because as he rightly stated, it's not recommended to use it globally.

**Note**: In any case I would use a *User variable* and **not** a *System-wide variable*, a co-worker could log with a different username on the same machine and still get a modified `NODE_PATH`.

But to do this locally for just **one** invocation on Linux you can simply call:

```
NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:/another/dir/node_modules npm start
```

It will use that `NODE_PATH` **only** for that invocation.

Same one time invocation on Windows:

```
@ECHO OFF

SET BASE_NODE_PATH=%NODE_PATH%
SET NODE_PATH=%BASE_NODE_PATH%;C:\another\dir\node_modules\
node index.js
SET NODE_PATH=%BASE_NODE_PATH%
```

### And...

You could also use a local dep like:

```
"dependencies": {
  "foo": "file:/another/dir/node_modules/foo"
}
```

But would require an `npm install` and it would copy the content of `foo` in the current package `node_modules` folder.

Comment: One constraint is that I need this all to happen programatically once the nodejs process has already started

Comment: Then I would use @Casper Beyer solution, be careful with the order of `module.paths` because `require` will stop at the first match.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite easy to achieve, just add absolute paths to module object

in your current script `/some/folder/node_modules/mine/my_module.js` add this

```
module.paths.push('/another/dir/node_modules'); 
                   //this must be absolute, like /Users/John/another/dir/node_modules

var foo = require('foo');
```

For demo, open node in terminal, and type `module.paths`, it will show all the path node will search for `require`, you just add your path

Comment: module is not global, It's scoped to the specific file where it was call, tested logging module.paths accross multiple files, have to add that little snippet to EVERY file for this hack to work

Comment: Yes, it is a hack tho, cuz you are tryin to access something outside of permitted directories

Comment: Pushing the path at the end of the `module.paths` array doesn't work, you have to use `unshift`.

Answer (score 2):

#### "require(X) from module at path Y"

Means calling require(X) from within a file located at path Y. So you practically can't change Y.

---

Although the above solutions work (modifying module.paths & requiring absolute path), you'll have to add those snippets to every file in your project where you need requiring the foreign modules.

Even more, modifying **module.paths** is not officially supported. So it's not guaranteed to work in future updates of node

---

## Introducing NODE_PATH

**NODE_PATH** is an environment variable that is set to a colon-delimited list of absolute paths.

Within those absolute paths, Node.js will search for a module that matches your require statement when all else has failed (Having indexed *node_modules* up to *File System Root* and still no match was found)

It is officially supported, although not recommended as it goes against convention (Your co-worker may not be aware of the **NODE_PATH** usage as there is no descriptive way of telling that in your project itself)

Notes:

- On Windows, **NODE_PATH** is delimited by semicolons instead of
  colons.
- Node doesn't look for node_modules within those paths like
  its default behavior, so your paths should be exactly where you
  contain needed modules. For example: "/another/dir/node_modules"

---

Detailed information can be found on NodeJs official document:
https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_the_global_folders

---

For those of you who are unaware of what environment variables is and how to set them, I have a windows screenshot that will get you started

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In simple lines, u can call your own folder as module :

For that we need: global and app-module-path module

here "App-module-path" is the module ,it enables you to add additional directories to the Node.js module search path And "global" is, anything that you attach to this object will b available everywhere in your app.

Now take a look at this snippet:

```
global.appBasePath = __dirname;

require('app-module-path').addPath(appBasePath);
```

__dirname is current running directory of node.You can give your own path here to search the path for module.